# Neovim automatically run command when opening a filetype from ftplugin file

Tags: neovim, ftplugin

I have Neovim setup with configurations for file types separated into ftplugin files.

I would like to have Neovim start the Goyo plugin when I open a markdown file. However, I would like to keep this logic outside of my `init.vim` for cleanliness.

I have a markdown config located in `...nvim/ftplugin/markdown.vim`. Neovim is able to read it.

Should I use autocmd? Or is there another method for doing this that is cleaner and easier? Also any references to the correct help pages in Neovim would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Consider the [vi.se] site for questions on Vim and NeoVim!

Comment: @filbranden That's a great idea. I'm going to post it there too.

Comment: Instead, you can ask a moderator of this site to migrate it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use an autocmd or anything, because the scripts under `ftplugin` are already loaded by an autocmd triggered when the filetype is actually set.

For example, for filetype `markdown`, the autocmd that loads `ftplugin` is equivalent to:

```
autocmd FileType markdown runtime! ftplugin/markdown.vim ftplugin/markdown_*.vim ftplugin/markdown/*.vim
```

So you can simply add a command, such as `Goyo`, to enable Goyo, inside such an `ftplugin` script.

Note that you can use a `ftplugin/markdown.vim` file, but if one already exists, you can also create a file named `ftplugin/markdown_goyo.vim` or `ftplugin/markdown/goyo.vim`, any and all of those will be loaded when a file with filetype `markdown` is opened.

If you want to have the `Goyo` command opened late, after all other `ftplugin` commands for that filetype have been executed (to prevent any interference and override all previous settings), then store it under `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin` rather than `~/.config/nvim/ftplugin`. The `after` subdirectory is added last to `'runtimepath'`, so the scripts stored there are executed last.

You'll find relevant documentation under [`:help filetype-plugin`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/usr_43.html#filetype-plugin).